# bootstrap grid need 10 columns to fill the width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have a bootstrap grid with 2-8-2

In the left hand 2 I have a menu which I want to collapse below 979px

All this is working.

However I would like the remaining 8-2 columns to fill up the width and to position the menu out of the way somewhere.

I suppose i could alter the width of the 8-2 with the media queries - but is there a better way

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.hidden classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to hide the menu after the breakpoint?

```
<div id="menu-div" class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with @PeteTNT's answer, you can change the widths of the remaining 8-2 cols, to 10 and 2 after the breakpoint..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">left</div>
   <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-10">main</div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">right</div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/Iuq0OH7Jxq

Comment: now that's helpful. However, I am stuck with joomla on this project which comes with bootstrap2.